# How to send text and image via mms in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My requirement is to send text as well as an image as MMS according to requirement but using asp.net with C#. I know how to send SMS but I don't know how to send mms in asp.net application. Is it possible through asp.net? If yes then how can we achieve this task?

Comment: You cannot achieve this without a third party application. What are you currently using to send sms and does that offer any MMS sending abilities?

Comment: OK Thanks for the valuable information.But can we attach an image to an sms and send using asp.net??

Comment: @Pwavel002 no, SMS is only text. MMS has different format and API. Actually there is little outdated info on how to send MMS using email, but I'd still recommend a proper 3rd party service. Bing is your friend (just not say G again)

Comment: @Pwavel002 I'm sure it is possible. But without knowing what you're currently using it is difficult to give you an answer. A quick search tells me it is possible through a third party .net API.

This API looks like it will do the job: http://www.nowsms.com/download-free-trial

Comment: You need a 3rd party API that supports sending MMS.